# How to ignore a parent element's padding

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to show full border  `class="line"` to ignore/exclude the padding without modifying the html?

For example:

```
<div class="padding">
 <section>
     <p>text</p>
  </section>

  <div class="line"> </div>

   <section>
     <p>text</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.padding {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.line {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tzq3o6tx/

I want the `<div class="line"> </div>` border to overlap the padding.

Comment: You can reset margins (commun practice) ex: p and line https://jsfiddle.net/tzq3o6tx/4/ but why not the padding in the first place :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add a negative margin on `.line` like so:

```
.line {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin:0 -20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tzq3o6tx/3/

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the width to be more than the padding and then set a starting point that is before the padding.

https://jsfiddle.net/tzq3o6tx/1/

```
.padding {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:200px;
}

.line {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```